# Recover an array of integer saved as a string

Tags: arrays, string, integer

This is an example array i stored in a string property:
[12, 15, 75, 60]

When i tried to retrieve it
and access the index number, it included every character that denotes the array, for example if i ask for array[0], it gives me '[', instead of '12', array[3] gives me ',' array[6] gives me '5' and so on.

How can blender Python read the string like it does with array?

I tried enclosing things in int(), it throws a message "string indices must be integers" or "invalid literal for int() with base 10

Thank for your advance response!
I didn't include any code snippet as this problem is simple enough to understand, thanks, more power

Comment: How did you end up with this string array?

Comment: I stored the array inside a name property and i want to retrieve it for later use, i want to know how to turn the string back into readable array format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a string array let's convert it this way.

```
a = '[12, 15, 75, 60]'
b = a[1:len(a)-1].split(",")

print(b[0])
```

If you want a int array let's convert it this way.

```
a = '[12, 15, 75, 60]'
b = list(map(int, a[1:len(a)-1].split(",")))

print(b[0])
```

Comment: Can you please explain this part? " a[1:len(a)-1] "? I want to better understand it

Comment: It takes a substring of any array. `string[start:end]` will take a substring from `start` index to `end-1` index. So in your case to avoid opening and closing bracket we skipped 0 and last index.

Comment: Ohhhhh, ok, that makes sense now